# Remove error border of form field in vue js

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I have a form, and during submission am showing a Red colour error border to each of the form fields. My requirement is that i want to remove those borders in focus event.

I want to implement it in my Vue JS project. i have already installed Js packages.

I wrote my code in "Mounted" function.

```
mounted: function () {

             $("body").on("focus", ".error-border", function () {
               $(this).removeClass("error-border")
             })
        }
```

Comment: Don't use jQuery to manipulate the DOM while you're using Vue, its a terrible ideia...

If jQuery makes any change to an element that Vue is managing (add a class to something for example), the Vue virtual DOM won't be aware of the change and Vue will overwrite it in the next update cycle.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have to use VueJS data to do the trick. For example, you could have a template like this...

```
<div id="app">
  <form action="">
    <input type="text" @focus="focused = true" @blur="focused = false">
    <p>{{ focused }}</p> // Displaying value to debug
  </form>
</div>
```

...and you Vue code could look like that

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
        focused: false
    }
  }
})
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g37cq140/11/) to try by yourself.

Using `@focus` will trigger the event when your input is focused and `@blur` when it's not. With that said, you can do whatever you want to change border color. I would use [VueJS watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) to change the color when `focused` changes.

For that part, I let you see the documentation I linked above.

Comment: I cant use this, because i have so many forms and fields, then i have to give this to each and every, thats why am using common function

Comment: If you make a component with the code above, you could call your component everywhere you want and use it. Another thing that you could look about is [VueJS Mixins](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html), which allows you to use VueJS code on a global page and do the stuff you want.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you're using The Body tag to trigger the focus event to remove the css class however this behavior mostly is using with inputs.

If you want to remove a class from an element when a focus event occurs you might use @focus directive .. here an example:

```
<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    displayError : true
  },

});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="app">
<input 
 @focus="displayError = false" 
 :class="{'error-border': displayError}” />

</div>
```

CSS

```
.error-border {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

you might display the class within a computed property or as the example .

Answer (score 0):

**Quick note:** Try to see if a lightweight validation framework, like [vuelidate](https://vuelidate.netlify.com/), would be helpful for your code. Form validation can get really messy if you have a lot of inputs in your form.

I've created this fiddle which gives you an idea on how you could do this using vue methods attached to the `v-on:focused` event

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
     inputError: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
   toggleBorder: function(event) {
      this.inputError = true
      event.target.classList.remove('red-border')
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.red-border {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <form action="">
    <input type="text" @focus="toggleBorder" :class="{'red-border': inputError}">
  </form>
</div>
```

As mentioned in one of the comments, try to not use `jQuery` with vue values as you'll often have to write extra logic to make the two work together

Comment: Directly manipulating the DOM without jQuery is not really an improvement over directly manipulating the DOM with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost never a good idea to directly manipulate the DOM when working in Vue -- not with jQuery, not with vanillaJS.  You'll inevitably end up with collisions between the Vue and non-Vue code, when Vue overwrites parts of the DOM you've changed; and introduce bugs where the data model falls out of synch with the DOM representation of it.

Take advantage of the framework: let Vue worry about the DOM, and instead focus on the component data.

There are many ways to handle form validation; if you don't want to go all the way to a real [validation library](https://vuelidate.netlify.com) one simple strategy is to use computed functions to check each input's validity:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    foo: ''
  },
  computed: {
    fooIsInvalid() {
      return this.foo === '' // your validation rules here
    }
  }

});
```

```css
input.invalid {border-color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="foo" :class="{invalid: fooIsInvalid}">
</div>
```

Alternatively you could depend on focus and input events to set a data model value instead of a computed function:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    foo: '',
    fooIsInvalid: false
  },
  methods: {
    validate() {
      this.fooIsInvalid = !!(this.foo === '')
    }
  }
});
```

```css
input.invalid {border-color: red}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="foo" @focus="validate()" @input="validate()" :class="{invalid: fooIsInvalid}">
</div>
```

Another approach would be that suggested by the [Vue Cookbook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/form-validation.html) (basically a single "errors" array, filled on submit, instead of separate variables for each form field).  Or for a more reusable approach you could build your own input field component that sets its own "isValid" variable based on its v-model (though at this point you'd be basically reinventing existing validation libraries, and should probably just use existing code.)